# How to test mongo db transaction rollback

Tags: java, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am newbie to MongoDB i implemented transactional feature in one of my application, as per my requirements i need to persist data into different collections in the same database. Below is the code snippet for the same

In Tuple3 first element is database, second element is collection and third element is data i want to persist which is coming as json string which i am converting to bson document

```
 ClientSession clientSession = mongoClient.startSession();
        try {
            clientSession.startTransaction(transactionOptions);
            for (Tuple3<String, String, String> value: insertValues) {
                MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient
                        .getDatabase(insertValues.f0)
                        .getCollection(insertValues.f1);
                Document data= Document.parse(insertValues.f2);
                log.info(String.format("Inserting data into database %s and collection is %s", insertValues.f0, insertValues.f1));
                collection.insertOne(clientSession, data);
                clientSession.commitTransaction();
            }
        } catch (MongoCommandException | MongoWriteException exception) {
            clientSession.abortTransaction();
            log.error(String.format("Exception happened while inserting record into Mongo DB rolling back the transaction " +
                    "and cause of exception is: %s", exception));
        } finally {
            clientSession.close();
        }
```

Below are transaction options i am using

```
 TransactionOptions transactionOptions = TransactionOptions.builder().readConcern(ReadConcern.LOCAL).writeConcern(WriteConcern.W1).build();
```

Below is MongoClient method with MongoClientOptions i am taking Mongo DB Connection string as input to this method

```
public MongoClient getTransactionConnection(String connectionString) {
    MongoClientOptions.Builder mongoClientOptions = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
            .readConcern(ReadConcern.LOCAL)
            .writeConcern(WriteConcern.W1)
            .readPreference(ReadPreference.primary())
            .serverSelectionTimeout(120000)
            .maxWaitTime(120000)
            .connectionsPerHost(10)
            .connectTimeout(120000);

    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(connectionString, mongoClientOptions);

    return new MongoClient(uri);
}
```

Till here it is good and it is inserting data to three different collection under the specified database. But when i try to some negative scenario i am trying to throw exception in try block which ideally should rollback the data for that particular client session if any error happens.

I am trying to throw exception by using count variable which will increment and for if count value is equal to 1 i am throwing exception which should abort the transaction and rollback if any data is written to database but what i am seeing it is writing to one of the collection and throws exception after that stops the program but it is not rolling back the data written to collection actually. I am trying something like this below

```
ClientSession clientSession = mongoClient.startSession();
int count = 0;
            try {
                clientSession.startTransaction(transactionOptions);
                for (Tuple3<String, String, String> value: insertValues) {
                    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient
                            .getDatabase(insertValues.f0)
                            .getCollection(insertValues.f1);
                    Document data= Document.parse(insertValues.f2);
                    log.info(String.format("Inserting data into database %s and collection is %s", insertValues.f0, insertValues.f1));
                    collection.insertOne(clientSession, data);
                    if(count == 1){
                    throw new MongoException("Aborting transaction.....");
                }
                count++;
                    clientSession.commitTransaction();
                }
            } catch (MongoCommandException | MongoWriteException exception) {
                clientSession.abortTransaction();
                log.error(String.format("Exception happened while inserting record into Mongo DB rolling back the transaction " +
                        "and cause of exception is: %s", exception));
            } finally {
                clientSession.close();
            }
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong i am using Mongo DB version 4.0 deployed using Azure CosmosDB  Api. Please help me in resolving this issue thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos DB does not have transaction support outside of a single partition (shard) of a single collection. This limitation exists regardless of API in use (in your case, MongoDB API). This is why you're not seeing the behavior you're expecting. Note: this is mentioned in the [Cosmos DB MongoDB compatibility docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-40#transactions).

You'll need to come up with your own implementation for managing data consistency within your app.